# Cors Error when public application call private local Web API

Tags: c#, angular, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, private-network-access

I have a problem with my public  hosted  application the frontend is in Angular 13 and the backend is .Net Core Web API in C# (local) hosted in IIS 10.
The problem is when i try to make a web api call i have this error in the browser Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myprivatewebapiIP/MyController/Method...' from origin 'http://www.(mypublicfrontdomain).com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in-more-private adress space 'private'

I tried to add this in the web.config of the Web API :

```
 <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network" value="true" />
                 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```

but it doesn't work
and I tried also this in startup.cs :

```
builder.WithOrigins("http://www.(mypublicfrontdomain).com")
```

and

```
builder.AllowAnyOrigins()
```

but it doesn't work.
Any help please? Thanks

Comment: `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` <-- This is _dangerous_ - you should use an explicit allow-list (aka a whitelist) of known origins instead.

Comment: _"The request client is not a secure context"_ <-- This means you need to be using `https://` for everything. Why is your "mypublicfrontdomain.com" website not served over TLS?

Comment: => https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/

Comment: I tried to set builder.WithOrigins("http://www.(mypublicfrontdomain).com") in API and  Access-Control-Allow-Origin value="http://www.(mypublicfrontdomain).com" in web.config but it doesn't work

Comment: Check the request url whether the published application and the local application both using http request or not? Try to use the same kind of request, http or https. Besides, you can also try to add the `Access-Control-Request-Private-Network: true` in the request header.

Comment: I tried Control-Request-Private-Network: true in front and back ...not working too. I'm trying to make the front secured with an SSL certificate.

Comment: For the moment the solution that i taked is also to expose publically the api and set  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://www.(mypublicdomain).com" /> and <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" /> and in the code of api builder.WithOrigins("http://www.(mypublicfrontdomain).com"). I will pass both front and back into https with SSL very soon. Thanks for you help!